# retrieve the contents of the firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I created this simple function (according to this guide: https://medium.com/@jamesmarino/getting-started-with-react-native-and-firebase-ab1f396db549)

```
export function getNameOfUserToKill(userID, gameID, callback) {
  let path = '/games/' + gameID + '/' + userID;
  fb
    .database()
    .ref(path)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      var nameOfUserToKill = '';

      if (snapshot.val()) {
        nameOfUserToKill = snapshot.val().userToKill;
      }

      callback(nameOfUserToKill);
    });
}
```

But I don't know how to finally get the data...
Should I do `nameOfUserToKill = getNameOfUserToKill(USER1234, GAME65754)` ? I don't know what "callback" means. Thank you for your help.

---

So I can do it:

```
var nameOfUserToKill = '';

export function getNameOfUserToKill(userID, gameID) {
  let path = '/games/' + gameID + '/' + userID;
  fb
    .database()
    .ref(path)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      nameOfUserToKill = '';

      if (snapshot.val()) {
        nameOfUserToKill = snapshot.val().userToKill;
      }
    });
}

var user = nameOfUserToKill;
```

Comment: you do not need a callback to retrieve the data, check this also: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the content of the Firebase Database:

```
 let path = '/games/' + gameID + '/' + userID;
fb.database().ref(path).on('value', snapshot => {
  var nameOfUserToKill = '';
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    nameOfUserToKill = snapshot.val().userToKill;
  }
```

`nameofUserToKill` will contain the data that is retrieved.